# Change words on ‘Log in’ and ‘Register’ buttons on Woocommerce

Tags: plugins

Can anyone point me in the right direction to change the text on the two buttons on [this page](https://playtada.com/register/).

I want to change the words ‘log in’ and ‘register’ to something different!

Hope you can help!

Cheers

Tom

Comment: It's not working for me....do you have any other code?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add the following code to your theme's functions.php file.  If you haven't already you should create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), so you don't lose your edits when the theme updates.

**Update the Log In text**

```
function custome_login_btn(){
    add_filter('gettext', 'custome_login_btn_text', 10, 2);
}

function custome_login_btn_text($translation, $text){
    if ('Log In' == $text) {
        return 'MY NEW TEXT';
    }
    return $translation;
}

add_action( 'login_form', 'custome_login_btn' );
```

**Update the Register text**

```
function register_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Register',  'MY NEW TEXT',  $translated);
    return $translated;
}

add_filter(  'gettext',  'register_text'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'register_text'  );
```

Obviously, change the "MY NEW TEXT" part in each function.

Both functions are tested and work.

**Edit** - For your particlular

```
function login_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Log In',  'MY NEW TEXT',  $translated);
    return $translated;
}

add_filter(  'gettext',  'login_text'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'login_text'  );
```

Comment: Thanks RiddleMe This. The Register piece works perfectly but the code is having no effect on the login button! Would you have any idea why?

Comment: I edited my answer, that last piece of code will change it

Comment: Great that is the ticket! Thanks for your help really appreciated! Good one...